# Viewpager gives Grow heap size in android?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, heap-memory

i am implementing  the infinite view pager for this i have take 3 views in view pager and one xml file which contain one imageview and one videoview  i add this xml in to this 3 views left middle and right when videowill come imageview gone and when imageview will come videoview gone in 3 main views. but when i run the app my app will give heap size.i don't understand why app give heap.

here i put my complete code with logcat .

> Logcat

```
10-15 12:51:56.840: I/dalvikvm-heap(32135): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.850MB for 2073616-byte allocation
10-15 12:51:56.850: D/dalvikvm(32135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 10% free 6495K/7148K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
10-15 12:51:57.080: D/dalvikvm(32135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 10% free 6496K/7168K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
10-15 12:51:57.080: I/dalvikvm-heap(32135): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.827MB for 2073616-byte allocation
10-15 12:51:57.100: D/dalvikvm(32135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 8% free 8521K/9196K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
10-15 12:52:05.400: E/position scrolled(32135): position--->2
10-15 12:52:05.400: E/position scrolled(32135): iiii--->1
10-15 12:52:05.400: V/position next(32135): ---->
10-15 12:52:06.030: D/next called(32135): --->0
10-15 12:52:06.050: D/dalvikvm(32135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 41K, 8% free 8527K/9196K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
10-15 12:52:06.060: I/dalvikvm-heap(32135): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.811MB for 2073616-byte allocation
10-15 12:52:06.070: D/dalvikvm(32135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 10552K/11224K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
10-15 12:52:06.290: D/dalvikvm(32135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 33K, 6% free 10553K/11224K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
10-15 12:52:06.300: I/dalvikvm-heap(32135): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.790MB for 2073616-byte allocation
10-15 12:52:06.310: D/dalvikvm(32135): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 12578K/13252K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
```

> Mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.copyimagetosdcard;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myplaylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    String[] sslideimagearray={"/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/201410141503550814.jpg",
                             "/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/201410141504120735.jpg",
                             "/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/201410141504190108.mp4",
                             "/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/201410141504490486.jpg",
                             "/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/201410141504530577.m4v" };
    int i=0;
    boolean next=false;
    boolean previous=false;
    Runnable runnable;
    final Handler imagehandler = new Handler();
    private long runnableMill = 4000;
    boolean automode=true;
    String videoplay="false";
    MediaController controller;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        controller = new MediaController(this);
        awesomePager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.awesomepager);
        awesomeAdapter = new AwesomePagerAdapter(awesomePager);
        awesomePager.setAdapter(awesomeAdapter);
        awesomePager.setCurrentItem(1);
        awesomePager.setOnPageChangeListener(awesomeAdapter);
        awesomePager.setPageMargin(20);

        for(int k=0;k<5;k++){

            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();

            if(k==0 || k==1 || k==3){
                map.put("type", "image");
            }
            else{
                map.put("type", "video");
            }

            map.put("path", sslideimagearray[k]);

            myplaylist.add(map);

        }

        Log.d("myplaylist","--->"+myplaylist.size());
        Log.d("myplaylist","--->"+myplaylist);

        runnable = new Runnable()
        {

            public void run()
            {   // slider image run


                Log.v("runnable iiiii","---->"+i);
                Log.v("videoplay","---->"+videoplay);


                 if(videoplay.equals("true"))
                 {     

                 }
                 else
                 {

                        if(i==myplaylist.size())
                        {
                            i=0;    
                        }

                        if(i==0)
                        {   
                                runnableMill = 10000;
                                imagesautomode();
                                i++;
                        }     
                        else
                        {   
                            automode=true;
                            imagesautomode();
                            runnableMill = 10000;
                            i++;
                        }
                }   
                imagehandler.postDelayed(this, runnableMill); // for interval
            }

        };

        imagehandler.postDelayed(runnable,runnableMill);


    }


private class AwesomePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
    public AwesomePagerAdapter(ViewPager p) {
        super();

        LayoutInflater inflater= LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);

        mLeft=inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagevideo,null);
        p.addView(mLeft);

        mMiddle=inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagevideo,null);
        p.addView(mMiddle);

        mRight=inflater.inflate(R.layout.imagevideo,null);
        p.addView(mRight);

        lImageview=(ImageView)mLeft.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        mImageview=(ImageView)mMiddle.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        rImageview=(ImageView)mRight.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        lVideoview=(VideoView)mLeft.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mVideoview=(VideoView)mMiddle.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        rVideoview=(VideoView)mRight.findViewById(R.id.videoView);


    Log.d("constructor called","----->");   

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {


        Log.e("position scrolled","position--->"+position);
        Log.e("position scrolled","iiii--->"+i);
        if(automode){
            i--;
            automode=false;
        }


        if(position==0){

            previous=true;
            next=false;

            Log.v("position previous","---->");
        }
        else{
            next=true;
            previous=false;

            Log.v("position next","---->");

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
        if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

            // if automode true than we need to adujust i value for display because it was auto incrementd in handler
            if(automode){



                    if(next){

                        Log.d("next called"," auto mode"+i);

                            if(i==myplaylist.size()){
                                i=0;
                            }

                    }
                    else{

                        Log.d("previous called"," auto mode"+i);

                        if(i==0){
                            i=myplaylist.size()-1;
                        }else{
                            i--;
                            i--;
                            if(i<0){
                                i=0;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    automode=false;
            }
            else{

                automode=false;

                if(next){

                    Log.d("next called","--->"+i);

                    if(i==myplaylist.size()-1){
                        i=0;
                    }
                    else{
                        i++;
                    } 

                }else{

                    Log.d("previous called","--->"+i);

                    if(i==0){
                        i=myplaylist.size()-1;
                    }
                    else{
                        i--;
                    }

                }

            }

            images();


            awesomePager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS;
    }

    /**
     * Create the page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
     * for adding the view to the container given here, although it only
     * must ensure this is done by the time it returns from
     * {@link #finishUpdate()}.
     *
     * @param container The containing View in which the page will be shown.
     * @param position The page position to be instantiated.
     * @return Returns an Object representing the new page.  This does not
     * need to be a View, but can be some other container of the page.
     */

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return mLeft;
            } else if (position == 1) {
                return mMiddle;
            } else {
                return mRight;
            }

            //return tv;
    }

    /**
     * Remove a page for the given position.  The adapter is responsible
     * for removing the view from its container, although it only must ensure
     * this is done by the time it returns from {@link #finishUpdate()}.
     *
     * @param container The containing View from which the page will be removed.
     * @param position The page position to be removed.
     * @param object The same object that was returned by
     * {@link #instantiateItem(View, int)}.
     */

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(View collection, int position, Object view) {
            //((ViewPager) collection).removeView((View) view);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==(object);
    }

}
private ViewPager awesomePager;
private static int NUM_AWESOME_VIEWS = 3;
private AwesomePagerAdapter awesomeAdapter;

ImageView mImageview;
ImageView lImageview;
ImageView rImageview;

VideoView lVideoview;
VideoView mVideoview;
VideoView rVideoview;

private View mLeft;
private View mRight;
private View mMiddle;

public void images(){

    automode=false;
    videoplay="false";

    if(i==0 && myplaylist.size()>=2){

        String type=myplaylist.get(myplaylist.size()-1).get("type").toString();
        String path=myplaylist.get(myplaylist.size()-1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){

            if(lImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                lImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path, 0);
        }else{
            lImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(mImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               mImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,1);
        }else{
            videoplay="true";
            nextVideo(path);
        }

        type=myplaylist.get(i+1).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(i+1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(rImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               rImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,2);
        }else{
            rImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        /*
        lImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[sliderImageArray.length-1]);
        mImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[0]);
        rImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i+1]);
        */
    }
    else if(i==0 && myplaylist.size()==1){

        String type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        String path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){

            if(lImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                lImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }   
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path, 0);
        }else{
            lImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(mImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               mImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,1);
        }else{
            videoplay="true";
            nextVideo(path);
        }

        type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(rImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               rImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,2);
        }else{
            rImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    }   
    else if(i==myplaylist.size()-1){

        String type=myplaylist.get(i-1).get("type").toString();
        String path=myplaylist.get(i-1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(lImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                lImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path, 0);
        }else{
            lImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }   

        type=myplaylist.get(i).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(i).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(mImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                mImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,1);
        }else{
            videoplay="true";
            nextVideo(path);
        }


        type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(rImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               rImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,2);
        }else{
            rImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        /*
        lImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i-1]);
        mImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i]);
        rImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[0]);
        */
    }
    else{

        String type=myplaylist.get(i-1).get("type").toString();
        String path=myplaylist.get(i-1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(lImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                lImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path, 0);
        }else{
            lImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }   

        type=myplaylist.get(i).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(i).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(mImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               mImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,1);
        }else{
            videoplay="true";
            nextVideo(path);
        }


        type=myplaylist.get(i+1).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(i+1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(rImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               rImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,2);
        }else{
            rImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);             
        }

        /*
        lImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i-1]);
        mImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i]);
        rImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i+1]);
        */
    }

}

public void imagesautomode(){

    videoplay="false";

    automode=true;


    if(i==0 && myplaylist.size()>=2){

        String type=myplaylist.get(myplaylist.size()-1).get("type").toString();
        String path=myplaylist.get(myplaylist.size()-1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){

            if(lImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                lImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }   
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path, 0);
        }else{
            lImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(mImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               mImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,1);
        }else{
            videoplay="true";
            nextVideo(path);
        }

        type=myplaylist.get(i+1).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(i+1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(rImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               rImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,2);
        }else{
            rImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        /*
        lImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[sliderImageArray.length-1]);
        mImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[0]);
        rImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i+1]);
        */
    }
    else if(i==0 && myplaylist.size()==1){

        String type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        String path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){

            if(lImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                lImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }   
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path, 0);
        }else{
            lImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(mImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               mImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,1);
        }else{
            videoplay="true";
            nextVideo(path);
        }

        type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(rImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               rImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,2);
        }else{
            rImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

    }   
    else if(i==myplaylist.size()-1){

        String type=myplaylist.get(i-1).get("type").toString();
        String path=myplaylist.get(i-1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(lImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                lImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path, 0);
        }else{
            lImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }   

        type=myplaylist.get(i).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(i).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(mImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                mImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,1);
        }else{
            videoplay="true";
            nextVideo(path);
        }


        type=myplaylist.get(0).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(0).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(rImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               rImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,2);
        }else{
            rImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        /*
        lImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i-1]);
        mImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i]);
        rImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[0]);
        */
    }
    else{

        String type=myplaylist.get(i-1).get("type").toString();
        String path=myplaylist.get(i-1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(lImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                lImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path, 0);
        }else{
            lImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            lVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }   

        type=myplaylist.get(i).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(i).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(mImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               mImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,1);
        }else{
            videoplay="true";
            nextVideo(path);
        }


        type=myplaylist.get(i+1).get("type").toString();
        path=myplaylist.get(i+1).get("path").toString();

        if(type.equalsIgnoreCase("image")){
            if(rImageview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
               rImageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            nextImage(path,2);
        }else{
            rImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            rVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);             
        }

        /*
        lImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i-1]);
        mImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i]);
        rImageview.setImageResource(sliderImageArray[i+1]);
        */
    }

}



private void nextVideo(String path){

    videoplay="true";

    mImageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    if(mVideoview.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
        mVideoview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    mVideoview.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
    mVideoview.setMediaController(null);
    controller.setMediaPlayer(mVideoview);

    mVideoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

       public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                    long duration = mVideoview.getDuration();

                    Log.e("Video Prepared","---->"+duration);
                    mVideoview.start();

                    imagehandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    imagehandler.postDelayed(runnable, duration);


       }
   });


    mVideoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
    {
           @Override
           public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) 
           {

               mp.reset();

               videoplay="false";
               //images();


           }
    });

    mVideoview.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {

            images();

            return true;
        }

    }); 

}


private void nextImage(String path,int position) 
{
    try 
    {

        imagehandler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        imagehandler.postDelayed(runnable, runnableMill);
        videoplay="false";


        DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int imageWidth = (int) ( (float) metrics.widthPixels / 1.5 );
        int imageHeight = (int) ( (float) metrics.heightPixels / 1.5 );

        path=path.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ");
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        bmp =loadResizedBitmap(path, imageWidth, imageHeight, false);
        if(bmp!=null){

            if(position==0){
                lVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                lImageview.setImageDrawable(null);
                lImageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                lImageview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }
            else if(position==1){
                mVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mImageview.setImageDrawable(null);
                mImageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                mImageview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }
            else if(position==2){
                rVideoview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                rImageview.setImageDrawable(null);
                rImageview.setImageBitmap(bmp);
                rImageview.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
            }

        } 

    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {   
    }

}

public static Bitmap loadResizedBitmap( String filename, int width, int height, boolean exact ) 
{
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename, options );
    if ( options.outHeight > 0 && options.outWidth > 0 ) {
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        while (    options.outWidth  / options.inSampleSize > width
                && options.outHeight / options.inSampleSize > height ) {
            options.inSampleSize++;
        }
        options.inSampleSize--;
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filename, options );
        if(bitmap != null && exact ) {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap( bitmap, width, height, false );
            System.gc();

        }
    }

    return bitmap;
}


}
```

> activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.copyimagetosdcard.MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/awesomepager"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> imagevideo.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
     >

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
         />

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone" 
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` inside `application` tag assign `largeHeap` as `true`.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

It may help you.

Comment: is there any issue with viewpager because i was inflating layout for view ?

Comment: ok Mahesh create a folder in assets folder,put your images file in the folder and then load image from that folder then you didn't get that error again

Comment: i have set this images as a demo after this i need to download the image from server store in sdcard and display in adapter it is like sync sdcard with server means if image will add on server than automatically download image in sdcard and add in list for display in view pager